# Create a Typescript TypeChecker without using ts.createProgram?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-compiler-api

I'm doing some reflection using the typescript library. Primarily, I'm using `ts.createSourceFile` and passing along files stored in memory. This works really well and I can move through the nodes easily to match up binding syntax (in the html files) with the ViewModels (typescript) to make sure the access is good.

My problem is I would like to do some basic type checking now with the resulting ts.SourceFile objects I have. Thus far I've only been able to track the `TypeChecker` interface back to the `Program` class. Unfortunately, `ts.createProgram` takes paths to files, while I want to pass the `SourceFile` collection I already have.

Is there a way for me to do Type Checking using the `ts.SourceFile` objects I already have? All I really need to know is if the right side is assignable to the left, where I have the type nodes for both.

Answer (score -6):

You could use `ts.createSourceFile()` like so:

```
let sourceCode = fs.readFileSync(commander.file);
let sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(commander.file, sourceCode.toString(), ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015, true);
visitNode(sourceFile);
```

And then in the `visitNode` function, you can access to the `NodeObject` node which expose the `TypeChecker` info :

```
function visitNode(node: NodeObect) {    
  recognize(node);
  node.getChildren().forEach(c => visitNode(c));
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, this approach doesn't give access to the type information, only to the syntax tree.

Comment: yes, that's true. You won't have access to the static type. However, you could use the `ts.SyntaxKind` interface as a workaround.

Comment: SyntaxKind only indicates whether a node is Literal or Identifier, CallExpression, etc. I believe it's difficult to build type info from it. Type nodes from what we written in code is not enough, we should infer more from those